# Images are not visible in surface View

Tags: android, surfaceview

I created a lockscren for ICS. In my code I have changed my view from View to surface view to increase the efficiency. After that the images are not visible. But the images are drawing(Found it by putting logs).

[Please Find the code here](http://pastebin.com/m1MMaRVb)